# Error: Failed to create startup dialogue Eclipse

Tags: linux, eclipse

I have tried to install the darkest dark theme on Eclipse with DevStyle on Ubuntu. Now whenever I try to launch it, it says:
[image: Eclipse Error Message Image.]

```
Fails to create improved startup dialogue, falling back to Eclipse standard dialogue. Please check Eclipse configuration logs for details.
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling eclipse many times and this STILL happens. I can't find my eclipse config logs (I have no idea where they are). Thank you in advance for help!

Comment: This is all DevStyle and their "improved" startup dialog. You should probably contact them about it. They haven't contributed it down to Eclipse itself, after all.

Comment: Please be aware that this plugin tries to cheat the Eclipse open source license by patching Eclipse at runtime (or to be more precise via loadtime weaving). This can cause issues and slow down Eclipse. Consider using a more ergonomic theme that doesn't have such issues if you don't like the themes built-in.

Comment: We're following up on our forums here: https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topic/cant-launch-eclipse-with-devstyle-and-darkest-dark-theme-installed/

Comment: Thank you so much @BrianFernandes, I have uninstalled my headless version of Java and installed the full version, and now Eclipse and DevStyle work fine!

Comment: Yes! Updating the `eclipse.ini` to use an Oracle JDK fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 1):

- update eclipse.ini setting so that it can use JDK instead of jre, worked for me

```
-vm
/programs/softwares/Java/jdk-13/bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=13
```

Comment: Yes (as [described here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM)), but better use the Java that is shipped with Eclipse as part of Eclipse and do not change `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11` because this is to provide a better error message at an earlier point in time and changing the value does not change the fact which minimum Java version is actually required.